# Continuity of Riemann Integral Regarding Integrator

Tags: riemann-integration

For $f \in R([a,b], \alpha)$ define

$F(x) = \int_a^xfd\alpha, x\in [a,b]$

show that :

i) $\alpha$ is continuous at some $x\in [a,b]\Rightarrow F$ is continuous at $x$

ii)$\exists \alpha'(x)$ and $f$ is continuous at $x$ for some $x \in [a,b]$$\Rightarrow$ $\exists F'(x)$ and $F'(x)=f(x)\alpha'(x)$

---

How to prove above claim?

Intuitively i)states that only existence of continuous point of $\alpha$ could guarantee the continuity of $F$. However, I can't imagine how this could be possible.

Comment: Your thoughts ?

Comment: @StubbornAtom no, it's from my textbook

Comment: I mean if you have any thoughts on the problem, show your work by clicking on the 'edit' button. It helps others to address your question better.

Comment: @stubbornAtom got it